# como soluciono el 1.#inf00

Tags: c

estoy haciendo un programa para calcular la anualidad vencida, pero me aparece un error a la hora de ejecutar que es el "1.#inf00" y no se como solucionarlo investigue un poco y dice que es por desbordamiento de variable pero no e encontrado forma de solucionarlo.
Programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
main()
{
    float C,R,t,T,n,c,cc,m;
    printf ("ingresa R=");
    scanf ("%f",&R);
    printf ("ingresar T=");
    scanf ("%f",&T);
    printf ("ingresa los dias=");
    scanf ("%f",&n);
    C=pow(1+T,-n);
    printf("%.2f \n",C);
    c=1-C;
    printf("%f \n",c);
    cc=c/t;
    printf("%f \n",cc);

    
}
```

Comment: Con qué datos estás probando el código? Ve a [edit] y añade ese _detalle_

Comment: La variable `t` no tiene un valor definido ._.

Comment: Muchos errores se solucionan inicializando las variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando declaras una variable de un tipo estándar en C, no se le asigna un valor por defecto.
Cuando escribes `float t;`, la variable `t` contendrá lo que sea que la memoria asignada a `t` tuviera antes de reservar la memoria.
Cualquier operación que hagas con `t` antes de darle un valor es [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido).
El programa utilizará lo que sea que haya en ese trozo de memoria.

Algunos compiladores pueden inicializar los `float` a `0.0`, pero eso es por diseño del compilador, no del lenguaje.
Si en tu caso fuera así, la variable `t` tendría un valor tal que si `c` fuera positivo, el resultado de la división sería infinito.

Un `float` en C puede valer infinito y al imprimirlo por consola obtienes `inf`.

Con respecto a tu pregunta concreta *¿Cómo solucionarlo?* es difícil contestar porque con el código que compartes es difícil saber lo que pretendes.